# Map Alt-{ijkl} for tab split navigation

Tags: key-bindings

On my previous setup, I used the following binding to move between my splits

```
nmap <silent> <A-Up> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-Down> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-Left> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-Right> :wincmd l<CR>
```

Now I want to switch them to something more vim-like, using the 'hjkl' keys instead of the arrow pad. To do such, I mapped it like this :

```
nmap <silent> <A-k> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-j> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-h> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <silent> <A-l> :wincmd l<CR>
```

But its not working.

Is there a specific thing to bind it to the `alt` key, or do I have to unbind it somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alt-key combos emit different things on different systems. One thing you can do is map the actual key code that your system emits. Instead of something like `<A-K>` enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. On my system that appears as `ë` but has the desired effect when I do `Alt-K` in Normal mode.

Of course, if you copy your vimrc file to a different system it may not work there.

**Important general tip:** Unless you have a definitive need to do otherwise *always* [use `nnoremap` rather than `nmap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) (same for `inoremap`, `cnoremap`, etc.)

Comment: Is there a way I can see what my system emits on the Alt-key combo?

Comment: Create the mapping the way I suggest and you'll see. Most places in Vim where you can input text you can do Ctrl-V then the Alt key and you'll see.

Comment: I ended up mapping my split nav on `Ctrl-{hjkl}`, and put the tab nav on `Ctrl-{op}`, thanks for the help

Comment: No problem. Were you able to get things working with `Alt` (even if you decided to use something else)?

Comment: No, I was not able to get things working with `Alt`, but I did not look far.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, well if you come back to it let me know...it should work. Also take a look at the update to my answer as it has an important general tip.

Comment: I ran into this when migrating my Vim config from Windows to OSX. The `alt` mappings should work as long as you follow those steps: while in insert mode just enter the combo you want, `nnoremap ` ctrl-r alt-k ` your-command`. After the C-r you'll get a new prompt and then you'll see what A-k emits.